# Let $f(z)=z^2, g(z)=z-1,h(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ be functions defined on $\Bbb{C}$, what is the derivative of their composition?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f\left(z\right)=z^2,\:g\left(z\right)=z-1,\:h\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{z}$ be functiones defined on $\mathbb {C}$, what is the derivative of $\left(f\:\circ h\:\circ \:g\right)$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$.

I presume the solution would involve some variation of multivariable chain rule for complex-valued functions, but, evidently, I seem to lack the brain power to figure this out all by myself.

Comment: Does $(f \circ h \circ g)[z]$ signify $f\{h[g(z)]\}$ or $g\{h[f(z)]\}$?

Comment: these functions are holomorphic on their required domains, so actually you can just use the usual single-variable chain rule like $\mathbb{C}$ was never mentioned!

Comment: $f \circ g \circ h = \frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$, now you can differentiate this function itself.

Comment: @thorimur Re my previous comment/question, is there a universally accepted convention for interpreting $(f \circ h \circ g)[z]$?

Comment: @Kaind Did you intend $f \circ h \circ g$?

Comment: @user2661923 yes, it's the one that changes the notation as little as possible: $(f \circ g \circ h)(z) = f(g(h(z)))$

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, that's what I intended. Universally accepted convention is innermost function is applied first.

Answer (score 0):

(f∘h∘g)  = 1/(z−1)^2
\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-1\right)^2}\right)=-\frac{2}{\left(z-1\right)^3}

Thanks for your advice, guys!